# How to display the user's game score on-screen in real-time to other user playing on in group with first user?

Tags: javascript, push, real-time, alert

If multiple or two users are playing a game in team, how change in core of 1 user 1 can be reflected on score of user-2 in real time?

Comment: You can do this with WebSockets plus a broker like hive or mosquitto. Google them, you will understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it thought back-end. Here and example of NodeJS real-time chat https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ the main idea would be the same.

Comment: i haven't worked on nodejs, will it be scale-able if i have million of users?Eg if am playing game like Fantasy cricket,i have to reflect changes to million of users who are subscribed

Comment: I think yes. But I didn't tried with millions, just 3-4 test users. It is probably already moving to hardware issue, if you have some free test server with one core and 1 GB ram and slow internet, probably it would not be able to handle so many connections.